# How to show information from API when using search box in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, search

I'm using the Star Wars API to build a React JS project. The aim of my app is to be able to search for characters.

Here is my code for the search component in the my app.

At the moment I'm able to retrieve data the API and show the information on the page but I can't work out how to show this information when it's searched for.

Any ideas?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      query:'',
      peoples: [],
    }
  }

 onChange (e){
   this.setState({
     query: e.target.value
   })
  if(this.state.query && this.state.query.length > 1) {
     if(this.state.query.length % 2 === 0){
       this.componentDidMount()
     }
   }
 }

componentDidMount(){
  const url = "https://swapi.co/api/people/";
  fetch (url,{
    method:'GET'
  }).then(results => {
    return results.json();
  }).then(data => {
    let peoples = data.results.map((people) => {
      return(
        <ul key={people.name}>
        <li>{people.name}</li>
        </ul>
      )
    })
    this.setState({peoples: peoples});
    console.log("state", peoples)
  })
}

 render() {
   return (
     <form>
       <input
         type="text"
         className="search-box"
         placeholder="Search for..."
         onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
       />
       {this.state.peoples}
     </form>
   )
 }
}

export default Search
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could put your `fetch` in a separate function instead of in `componentDidMount` and call that when the component mounts and when your query changes.

Since you might be creating multiple requests if the user types quickly, you could use a [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce) to only send one request, or use something that verifies that you always use the result of the latest request, like e.g. a `token`.

**Example**

```
class Search extends Component {
  token = null;
  state = {
    query: "",
    people: []
  };

  onChange = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      query: value
    });

    this.search(value);
  };

  search = query => {
    const url = `https://swapi.co/api/people?search=${query}`;
    const token = {};
    this.token = token;

    fetch(url)
      .then(results => results.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (this.token === token) {
          this.setState({ people: data.results });
        }
      });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.search("");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="search-box"
          placeholder="Search for..."
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        {this.state.people.map(person => (
          <ul key={person.name}>
            <li>{person.name}</li>
          </ul>
        ))}
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `setTimeout()` for this search functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define it in diff function to manage easy.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Search extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            query: null,
            peoples: [],
        }
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.serachPeople(this.state.query);
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({ query: e.target.value }, () => {
            if (this.state.query && this.state.query.length > 1) {
                if (this.state.query.length % 2 === 0) {
                    this.serachPeople(this.state.query);
                }
            } else {
                this.serachPeople(this.state.query);
            }
        })
    }

    serachPeople(query) {
        const url = "https://swapi.co/api/people/";

        if (query) {
            // if get value ion query so filter the data based on the query.
            fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET'
            }).then(results => {
                return results.json();
            }).then(data => {
                let peoples = data.results.filter(people => people.name === query).map((people) => {
                    return (
                        <ul key={people.name}>
                            <li>{people.name}</li>
                        </ul>
                    )
                })
                this.setState({ peoples: peoples });
                console.log("state", peoples)
            })
        } else {
            fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET'
            }).then(results => {
                return results.json();
            }).then(data => {
                let peoples = data.results.map((people) => {
                    return (
                        <ul key={people.name}>
                            <li>{people.name}</li>
                        </ul>
                    )
                })
                this.setState({ peoples: peoples });
                console.log("state", peoples)
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="search-box"
                    placeholder="Search for..."
                    onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                />
                {this.state.peoples}
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default Search;
```

I hope this will help for u. Let me know if u have any query.